# Viability of running XMLHttpRequest every second?

Tags: javascript

I have an application that gathers live JSON data every second from another server via XMLHttpRequest. After checking the Networks panel on Chrome, I have found that the size of each packet is about 697 bytes. I am unsure whether this is a high or a low number, and whether there are any potential problems running my application like so.

Example:

```
var exhaitch = new XMLHttpRequest();
var exlink = "wheremydatais.com";
exhaitch.onreadystatechange = function(){
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));}
}
exhaitch.open("GET", exlink, true);
exhaitch.send();
```

This javascript code is put inside an interval that is set to run every 1.5 seconds. The console log contains the updated data I want to use in my application.

I understand that ideally this would have been done using Node.js and Socket.io. However, much of this application has already been built over LAMP stack. So I am wondering what my options are if this method is unsustainable over the long term.

One thing I have looked into recently is socket.io without Node. Though I am still unclear how to go about that.

Comment: why use a timeout when you can just queue the next call from within the `onreadystatechange` ?

Comment: I don't think there might be any issue. The only thing is if the other server has any constrains regarding the number of calls per certain interval.

Comment: While socket.io is a great library for websockets, I very much suggest you look at the native Websocket API :)

Comment: Thanks. will do. Also, a comfort to know that there is nothing inherently bad with the way I am doing things as is. Saves me from having to delay for the time being.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more preferable and will scale better:

```
function getMyData(){

  var exhaitch = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var exlink = "wheremydatais.com";
  exhaitch.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
      console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      getMyData();
    }
  }
  exhaitch.open("GET", exlink, true);
  exhaitch.send();
}
```