# Viability of using XMLHttpRequest every second vs using web sockets?

Tags: javascript

I was hoping to get clarification regarding whether I should be using XMLHttpRequest to retrieve live data every second, or Web Sockets.

I had previously asked a [somewhat similar question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49226228/viability-of-running-xmlhttprequest-every-second), though this time I feel I have a somewhat better grasp on my options and would like to know a little more.

Previously, my fetch code was something like so:

```
var fetch = "";

startitall();
function startitall(){
   fetch = setInterval(livedata, 1000);    
}

function livedata(){
var exhaitch = new XMLHttpRequest();
var exlink = "wheremydatais.com";
exhaitch.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
    console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));}
  }
exhaitch.open("GET", exlink, true);
exhaitch.send();
}
```

After having done some reading I've learned that the issue with this is that the call is closed every time the data is sent, making it inefficient. This is where web sockets are typically called for, as they keep connections open when there are clients.

That being said, in my previous question I was introduced to a solution via the code below:

```
 function getMyData(){

  var exhaitch = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var exlink = "wheremydatais.com";
  exhaitch.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
      console.log(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      getMyData();
    }
  }
  exhaitch.open("GET", exlink, true);
  exhaitch.send();
}
```

I presume that the thinking in this answer is to have a new call running during the first `onchange` event, making it so that fresh data is acquired without the interruption of closing the connection.

What I want to know here is, performance wise, is this as viable as running web sockets instead? Does the XMLHttpRequest closing not still have a performance impact? Am I still not closing and opening new connections each call?

I am asking this to determine whether I should be changing my infrastructure to implement web sockets, or whether the XMLHttpRequest method suffices. I do not need 2-way data binding, and my data is around 600 bytes.

Insights would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on your application requirements.

If you expect users to remain on the page for a long time (lots of polling), or that there will potentially be many concurrent users, and that your payload will remain relatively small, sockets are probably the way to go.

If you expect users to bounce quickly, or otherwise increase your payload size significantly, it may be better to manage that with a dedicated GET route from your server.

I've seen large scale, high traffic websites use both methods, and I've personally used both methods with not much issue. Sockets are particularly easy to set up if you are using a Node.js backend and can support over 250,000 concurrent connections per instance.